# how to view an image saved in variable in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, variables

Multiple images are saved to variables, and I would like to view them and save them. I loaded the .mat file into MATLAB, and variables appeared in my workspace e.g. a,b,c,d; all have images stored in them. I'd like to access an image from "a".

Tried: imagesc(a,:,:,imagenumber) but get  Error using ==> imageDisplayParsePVPairs at 72
Invalid input arguments.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `imshow` function from Image Processing Toolbox:

```
imshow(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

imagesc should work, it all depends on what your variables size are and how you write the call to the function...

i.e.

```
a = eye(100,100);
imagesc(a); colormap gray
```

works fine;

if

```
a = rand(100,100,100);
imagesc(a(1,:,:));
```

or if a is an rgb image, `a(width,height,3)`, then use imshow as proposed by Romeo

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is wrong. If is a single image you should write

```
imagesc(a);
```

if is a (I'm assuming) RGB image

```
imagesc(a); colormap gray;
```

if grayscale.

If there are multiple images within the same variable you should use

```
imagesc(a(:,:,:,imagenumber))
```

for a RGB image

```
imagesc(a(:,:,imagenumber)); colormap gray;
```

for a grayscale